# Retrieve user command in Linux PAM module

Tags: c, linux, pam, netlink

I write a pam module that is called when user execute the sudo command. I have already got the *username*, *password*, *tty*, but now, I have to get the user command to encrypt.

If user exec

```
sudo ls -l
```

I have to get *ls -l*

I have no pam app for my module. (So I use only *pam_modules.h*) and my module is called first in */etc/pam.d/sudo*

I thought about using the **netlink** socket like [*pam_tty_audit*](https://fossies.org/dox/Linux-PAM-1.1.8/pam__tty__audit_8c_source.html), but I don't thinks this is the best method (or the most simple)

Have you any idea for getting the user command ?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the API documentation of sudo's authentication mechanisms](http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/cbf24072ad07/plugins/sudoers/auth/API), the command is not passed to the authentication backend, so PAM is the wrong place to do whatever you are trying to do. Consider writing a [sudo plugin](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/plugins.html) instead.